# How to pass values or data from a page to a webform using webform link field?

Tags: 8, webforms

If we have a link to a webform in a content type and we need to pass data or values to that webform from the fields available from the content type. How do we achieve this.

I'm using webform 8.x-5

I had hardly any success with 'Field Token Value' or setting default values from the available token of the webform build settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a webform reference field to the content type and put the default values in

**Default submission data (YAML)**

and you see this example provided by the field:

```
# This is an example of a comment.
element_key: 'some value'

# The below example uses a token to get the current node's title.
# Add ':clear' to the end token to return an empty value when the token is missing.
title: '[webform_submission:node:title:clear]'
# The below example uses a token to get a field value from the current node.
full_name: '[webform_submission:node:field_full_name:clear]
```

Comment: Thats for the reply let me try this and reply back

Comment: Could you please axaplin it a bit more specific .. if i have a field 'field_email' how can i access this in the web form once i click  'Link to webform' .. Thanks in advance

Comment: The link will contain ?_source_entity_type=node&source_entity_id=NID which will pass the node to the webform and allow you to use a [webform_submission:node:field_email:clear] token as the default data or even the element's default value.

Comment: I agree with the idea and the link definitely passes the the source_entity and ID. But a very few tokens are available to use as default values, like current-page:url. None of the [webform_submission:node] returns any value. I believe  [webform_submission:node] and related tokens are supposed to return the datas from 'The node that the webform was submitted from'. I'm using this webform in commerce product type. Will that may be a possibility the tokens are not available as commerce products are not exactly nodes.